# Angular 2 two-way component binding doesn't call parent ngOnChange

Tags: data-binding, angular, ngonchanges

I have created a plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8bwqkYQ6tqrpGwHT588y?p=preview

that shows the issue.

Basically, I have 2 components.  The first component has a 2-way binding of a property to the child component.

My parent component is:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { ChildComponent } from "./childComponent"

@Component({
    selector: 'parentComponent',
    template: `
    <div>
      <a href="#" (click)="selectedId = 0">Reset</a><br>
      <div>Parent SelectedId: {{selectedId}}</div>
      <childComponent [(selectedId)]="selectedId"></childComponent>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ChildComponent]
})

export class ParentComponent {
  @Input() selectedId: number;

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      console.log("Parent changes called!");
    }
}
```

and my child component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'childComponent',
    template: `
    <div>
      <div>Child SelectedId: {{selectedId}}</div> 
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() selectedId: number;
  @Output() selectedIdChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.selectedId = 100;
        this.selectedIdChange.emit(this.selectedId);
       }, 2000);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      console.log("Child changes called!");
    }
}
```

In the child, I set a timeout to change the value of selectedId programmatically after 2 seconds, then emit the value back to the parent.

This all works great, except for one thing... the ngOnChange of the parent is only being called once.

I would think that the parent would very much like to know if the child has changed the value, or else what is the point of 2 way binding??

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ngOnChange of the parent will only be called if App's `selectedId` changes, since that's what ParentComponent's input property is bound to.

If you want the parent to be notified of changes made in the child, bind to the `xChange` event (where `x` is the name of the input property) – i.e., break up the property and event bindings:

```
<childComponent [selectedId]="selectedId" (selectedIdChange)="changed($event)"></childComponent>
```

```
changed(newValue) {
  console.log('newValue', newValue);
  this.selectedId = newValue;
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eIjHXzhmYOL6yJktq7HM?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: @Scottie, well, sometimes you just want the parent (e.g., parent view) to update, and you don't need to be notified because you don't need to execute any logic when the child makes a change.  And you are correct, events emitted by EventEmitter don't bubble.  If you want multiple components to be notified of a single change, an Observable or a Subject in a shared service is the recommended approach.